# Background image in css

Tags: css, background

I have a .php file mostly all html. In this .php file I use an image for a background. It doesn't work. Nothing shows. I tried using different methods I found while googling for a solution. Still I can not place an image on my web page. I searched stackoverflow and again no solution.

Method 1:

```
body {
  background-image:url("file//C:\PictureList\brickWell.jpeg");
}
```

Method 2:

```
body {
  background-image:url('brickWell.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: post you php file and css so we can help fast.

Comment: Try `background:url('brickWell.jpeg");` instead. If that doesn't work, post a full demo of your code.

Comment: <head> 
<style type="text/css">
text {color:blue}
p {color:yellow}

body {
background-image:url('http://this.domain/brickWell.jpeg');

font-size: 16px; color:brown; style:bold;

}

</style>

</head>

Comment: Are you sure your image in a JPEG and not a JPG? Spelling counts!

Comment: Lol.  Yeah I got that.  I got it to work by calling locally.  url('brickWell.jpg');  How do I call the image from a folder?  Do I use url ('http://filedirectory');?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is where you have saved the image you want to use as background.

Try to place the image in the same directory where your php and use the following code:

```
body {

background-image:url("brickWell.jpeg"); }
```

And check that you use single quotes or double quotes but not combined.

Or please give us more information or code.

Comment: I do not need to provide the entire file of code.  Here is what counts. <head> 
<style type="text/css">
text {color:blue}
p {color:yellow}

body {
background-image:url('http://this.domain/brickWell.jpeg');

font-size: 16px; color:brown; style:bold;

}

</style>

</head>

Answer (score 0):

you should know where is  image file located .
if it locate in same folder with css file you should write :

```
body {

background-image:url('brickWell.jpeg"); }
```

if you will put code in php or html file the put full link after putting image in apache server 'WWW' folder , IE : try to put image in 'WWW' folder this put :

```
 body {

    background-image:url('http://localhost/brickWell.jpeg"); }
```

Comment: and check quotation mark and double quotation mark in  background-image:url('brickWell.jpeg"); , it should be same